# Points connected to graph

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I have $23$ points. Each pair of points has at most one edge connecting them.

For each of the $23$ points I add up each edge's degree. After doing the summation I get an integer $n$ such that $n \geq 207$.

How can I prove that there has to be some point that has a degree of at least $10$?

Does this have something to do with handshaking lemma?

Comment: $|E| \geq \lceil 207/2 \rceil = 104$. If each vertex has degree atmost $d$, then $|E| \leq nd/2$. Thus if no vertex has degree $\geq 10 \Rightarrow |E| \leq 23 * 9/2 = 103$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the degrees is just twice the number of edges, hence even, hence is in fact $\ge 208>207=9\cdot 23$. By pigeon-hole, one of the summands must be $>9$ (i.e., $\ge 10$, as desired).